# How can I print a ListView in C#

Tags: c#, listview, printing

Does any body have a solution for printing a multi column and row Listview in C#?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: What code have got at the moment? Have you tried anything or do you expect someone to just write the whole thing for you?

Comment: Did you know there is a ListView control for Windows.Forms, WPF and Asp.Net? Which one do you use?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using WinForms, the [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) project has a `ListViewPrinter` component which will do exactly that.

It is described in this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ListViewPrinter.aspx), but don't use the code from the article -- it's out of date. The most recent version is in the ObjectListView project.

It even handles grouping:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void SnapShotPNG(ListView source, string destination)
        {
            var lastHeight = source.Height;
            source.Height = 10000;
            Graphics canvas = source.CreateGraphics();            
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1000, 1000, canvas);
            source.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000));
            bmp.Save(destination);
            source.Height = lastHeight;
        }
```

Easy!!!

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).